# Не работает make clean

Tags: makefile

Есть 3 файла `main.cpp`, `fft32.cpp`, `gnuplot.cpp`. Попробовал использовать make для удобства сборки. Вот содержимое `Makefile`:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wfloat-equal -Wsign-conversion -Warray-bounds -Wdiv-by-zero -Wdouble-promotion

all: impulse

clean:
    rm -rf impulse *.o

impulse: main.o gnuplot.o fft32.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o impulse main.o gnuplot.o fft32.o
    
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.cpp
    
gnuplot.o: gnuplot.cpp gnuplot.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o gnuplot.o gnuplot.cpp

fft32.o: fft32.cpp fft32.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o fft32.o fft32.cpp
```

Собрал с помощью `make`. Далее пытаюсь очистить все, пишу в консоль `make clean`, выдает ошибку

```
rm -rf impulse.exe *.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf impulse.exe *.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Не удается найти указанный файл.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Уточните платформу где собираете?  P.S. Лучше конечно использовать [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) ну или [cmake](https://cmake.org/)

Comment: Скачал пакет mingw32-make из msys2, с помощью него пробовал

Comment: Тогда и создавайте не просто бинарник `impulse: main.o gnuplot.o fft32.o` а с учетом рассширения `impulse.exe: main.o gnuplot.o fft32.o`

Comment: Не помогло, такую же ошибку выводит в консоль

Comment: ну нет у вас в системе программы rm. используйте какой-нибудь аналог.

Comment: Какой например? Если в консоли прописать `rm *.o`, то все работает и удаляются объектные файлы.